# camera image conversion

Tags: android

```
    package map.demo;
 public class MapDemoActivity extends Activity {

        Button capture;
        ImageView image;
        int cameracode=100;
        Bitmap bm;
        Boolean result;
        FileOutputStream fos;
        File sd;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            capture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.capture);
            capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
                    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(i, cameracode);  
                }
            });

        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                        if(requestCode==100)
                        {



                            bm=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                            image.setImageBitmap(bm);


                            image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                            bm = image.getDrawingCache();

                                if(bm==null)
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image is null", 1000).show();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    try {

                                        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.jpg"));

                                        result=bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);

                                        fos.flush();
                                        fos.close();

                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                            }       
                        }

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

i am doing above code to capture image from camera and set image to image view
& convert image to jpeg,
But i does not get image, it shows null. i.e in my code bm=null after image capture.
but image view show me image which is by default for camera (i am using emulator to capture image).

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the image because you have not provided any image URI where the image will be saved.

Please see [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222151624/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/10/take-picture-in-android-with.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I might be missing something but do you have code for starting the camera simular to this:

```
public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // We're implementing the Callback interface and want to get notified
    // about certain surface events.
    getHolder().addCallback( this );
    // We're changing the surface to a PUSH surface, meaning we're receiving
    // all buffer data from another component - the camera, in this case.
    getHolder().setType( SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS );
}

public void surfaceCreated( SurfaceHolder holder ) {
    // Once the surface is created, simply open a handle to the camera hardware.
    //camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.setPreviewDisplay( holder );
    } catch( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged( SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height ) {
    // This method is called when the surface changes, e.g. when it's size is set.
    // We use the opportunity to initialize the camera preview display dimensions.
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged: " + width + "x" + height);
    Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    //p.set("orientation", "portrait");
    int w = p.getPreviewSize().width;
    int h = p.getPreviewSize().height;
    p.setPreviewSize( w, h );       
    camera.setParameters( p );

    // ...and start previewing. From now on, the camera keeps pushing preview
    // images to the surface.
    camera.startPreview();
}
```

and I assume you also set the permissions in the manifest like this:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Also be aware that the emulator will only show a checker board pattern if the camera is set up properly. The pattern must be squares if the aspect ratio is set correctly (rectangles means you have a distorted image).

Answer (score 0):

the problem I think here is, you are not providing ImageView the time to draw fully but instead you try to get the Cache even before it is there. So you always end up getting null and your Toast gets displayed. Instead here is a method. Check this out,

Remove this line and see how it goes.

```
 bm = image.getDrawingCache();
```

the reason is you have already saved the Captured Image to this Bitmap object and set it to the ImageView. So why do you rely on ImageView to get the bitmap object once again. If you want to reduce the size of the image you can use **createScaledBitamp** method from the Bitmap Class.

Comment: Good to hear.. so how about accepting this as the answer then .. :)